# Problem SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel however when I migrate my table using artisan i am thrown the following error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

This is my user migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('showname')->nullable();
            $table->string('business')->nullable();
            $table->string('NIP')->nullable();
            $table->string('PESEL')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('postalcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('comments')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

This is my products migration

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;


class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('category')->nullable();
            $table->date('launchdate')->nullable();
            $table->date('expirationdate')->nullable();
            $table->integer('billingperiod')->nullable();
            $table->integer('renewalprice')->nullable();
            $table->integer('internalcost')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users');
        });
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Please help me. I don't know what to do with this. I changed DB engine to Inno DB in databaase.php but it didn't helped at all.

Comment: You don't need this part `Schema::table('products'...` you can attach foreign key in ` Schema::create('products'...` function as well.

Comment: Based on the exception, it sounds like the data violates a foreign key constraint so it cant be created. Does it work if you crate the constraint inside the Schema::create instead of  after the table is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's `increments()` creates an "*Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column.*". You foreign key column `user_id` has to be of the exact same type as the column it is referencing.

In your `CreateProductsTable` migration, change

```
$table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
```

to

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

and try again.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: Or `$table->unsignedIntiger('user_id')->nullable()` if you prefer less chaining.